# WSO2 Identity Server Password Expiry

Tags: wso2

I'm using WSO2 Identity Server 5.0 for SAML SSO and need to have user passwords expire after n days. I found the following properties in identity-mgt.properties but I can't find any documentation on how to use them. Is this functionality implemented/available?

```
Authentication.Policy.Check.Password.Expire=false
Authentication.Policy.Password.Expire.Time=0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

These two properties had been introduced initially to IS planning to support password expiry, but the implementation was never done.

if **Authentication.Policy.Check.Password.Expire** is set to true, then the when the user updates the password, timestamp of password update is set as a user claim.

But **Authentication.Policy.Password.Expire.Time** is not logically used anywhere in the code base, and ideally should be removed.

Anyways, you can achieve the same functionality in a different way using [password policy authenticators](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+Password+Policy+Authenticator) in IS. Hope this helps.